# Is it OK to rollback superfluous snippet edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

What should I do when someone edits Stack Snippets into questions that do not include runnable code (such as with PHP or a framework not supported)? A few examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14265116
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14222002

They have been accepted, and have given the user the signal that there edit was good. This shouldn't be encouraged, and though I know it's highly discouraged to police a user, I decided to rollback these changes, getting rid of the snippets.

It happened that a [moderator rolled back my rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40479222/revisions), so it raises the questions:

- Should I rollback these changes that are completely superfluous/harm readability as they use snippets on unrunnable code?
- Are these edits even superfluous in the first place? Do they harm readability?
- What if the code includes external resources (such as local images and videos) and do not show up on Stack Snippets - which makes the edit superfluous (and harms readability) - should I reject/rollback that too?

Comment: You ever notice how people who laser-focus their edits on snippet conversions tend to say something along the lines of "Formatted correctly" or "Code was not properly formatted" as if regular code blocks were somehow *incorrect* code formatting?

Comment: @BoltClock I have - many, many times. I find it really annoying, and that's why I've always rejected and rolled back superfluous/actively harmful ones. Apparently that's not acceptable as far as I've seen, or is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I rollback these changes that are completely superfluous/harm readability as they use snippets on unrunnable code?

The one that was rolled back by a moderator is somewhat debatable. The snippet — and by extension the question — demonstrates a problem with JavaScript code. The PHP code that appears in the HTML is inconsequential and can easily be edited out of the Stack Snippet to keep the markup pure, while not affecting its ability to demonstrate the JavaScript problem.

Edits that convert code into Stack Snippets that aren't going to run anyway should be rolled back.

> Are these edits even superfluous in the first place? Do they harm readability?

Yes, edits that convert code into Stack Snippets are superfluous and/or harm readability if

- the snippet doesn't actually demonstrate the problem,
- the code is in a language that is not supported by Stack Snippets in the first place, or
- there is nothing to "demonstrate" or run anyway. For example, a question that's purely about marking up HTML doesn't benefit from visual demos since HTML isn't about visuals to begin with; those visuals only serve as a distraction.

> What if the code includes external resources (such as local images and videos) and do not show up on Stack Snippets - which makes the edit superfluous (and harms readability) - should I reject/rollback that too?

That's what I'd do. Even if the Stack Snippet could be modified to support external resources, unless you're intimately familiar with the code it's unlikely anyone else but the asker will be capable of doing so without fundamentally breaking the Stack Snippet's intended function.